# Changing [tips] to [challenges]

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this in a general sense, but here is the question where it arose:

[Mini Space Invaders](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/39938/14215) : [(revision history)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/39938/revisions)

What we have here is a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question asking for a shorter equivalent of the given code. It was edited into a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and I rolled it back to [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips).

I felt a bit uneasy rolling it back, but I thought it was the right thing to do. My question here is: **Should we attempt to change tips into challenges?**

There are clearly some cases where it could easily be done. This one for example could make a good, if simple, code golf. However, with all the recent talk about opening up to tips, I feel that it gives the impression that we don't *want* tips if we convert them.

For this challenge specifically, my reasoning went like this:

- We should keep the OP's intent intact unless it's off topic.
- The edit asked for extra code (to print/display the filled array) that wasn't in the original.
- A small bonus was included for this extra code.
- I already answered it as a tip, and the edit invalidated my answer (clearly I may be biased here).
- What was wrong with it being a tip?

Nevertheless, I wasn't *sure* I was doing the right thing. I completely agree that it could work well in either tag, so I'd like to ask for opinions from the community. If we reach a consensus about it (either way), that could help avoid back-and-forth editing situations like this in the future.

Comment: While I keep saying that tips are basically language-specific micro-optimisation challenges, I think there is a difference between a simple (language-specific) challenge and a question asking for advice: mostly in what the answers will be like. A good answer to an advice type question will probably explain in much more detail how the golfing was done, and maybe even present intermediate steps or suboptimal versions which might allow a shorter overall program in a slightly different context. Tips are about teaching the OP how to improve their golfing - I think that's fundamentally different.

Comment: Changing this sort of [tips]
 question to a [code-golf]
 would be [requiring minimum scores](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928/61384), which is discouraged.