# Things to avoid when writing challenges

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, challenge-quality, defaults

If there is something that you find annoying / counterproductive / unfair / detrimental / no longer funny in **challenges** (question posts), describe it in an answer here, and propose a recommended response. Voting will indicate whether that response has the backing of the community.

For example, you might suggest one of the following:

1. Comment linking here
2. Edit question
3. Close question
4. Delete question
5. Other (please specify)

Consider quoting from (rather than linking to) example challenges, as the fact that you are posting here makes it likely that the challenge may be edited making the link confusing for future readers.

---

For aspects of ***solutions*** (answer posts) to be avoided, see instead [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: I think that this question is directly targeting the "rationales for short code lengths" posing as a broader (but mostly useless) question.  I'd prefer if a different meta post were made specifically talking about the rationales, and allow the community to present both sides.

Comment: @NathanMerrill You're welcome to post a response here. Just give your reasoning and recommend no action. It should work just fine on this post.

Comment: This may be a good thing to feature, or put in some other high traffic location so it can be treated as a reference.

Answer (score 126):

## Cumbersome I/O formats

Generally, allow flexible input and output formats. People want to write code to do your task of, say, composing permutations, not reading/writing numbers in a particular semicolon-separated format, or from a file, or with input validation. For code golf, it's annoying when most of your byte count is boilerplate, especially when other languages read the format natively.

Allowing I/O in the language's native format (list, string, tuple, etc) is usually a better option. Yes, it makes comparisons between languages less exact, but that's worth it.

In particular, don't use long strings for outputs. Instead of "Why, yes, good sir or madam, this list is in fact a palindrome", let programs output 1/0 or True/False or general [Truthy/Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190/20260) values.

Of course, if your task is about specific formats, that's fine. ASCII art challenges usually require a precise output. A challenge to process certain file headers can expect a rigid input format.

Comment: I'm tempted to make a language that outputs `true` as `Why, yes, good sir or madam, this is in fact the case!`

Comment: In particular, as a bare minimum, no question should be more restrictive than the defaults https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods
(That is to say, no question should say things like "full program taking input over STDIN only, no single function answers")

Comment: @LyndonWhite There still are exceptions to that, of course.

Comment: How to turn any challenge into kolmogrov complexity

Answer (score 85):

## Rules inferred from test cases

Test cases are examples for people to check their understanding of the spec and the correctness of their code. They should not replace an explanation of how the output must relate to the input. (There are rare exceptions where it's straightforward, like a scaling ASCII art pattern.)

Don't leave readers guessing as to what the rules must be from examples. In particular, it can be unclear if the precise input/output format of the test cases is required. Also, additional requirements in test cases are liable to be missed by someone who starts coding before looking at them.

Comment: unless the entire challenge is one of those kolmos with: for each of these as input output the other thing

Answer (score 79):

## Making assumptions about language features

Unless you're writing a language-specific challenge, avoid terms specific to some class of languages, because these might not make sense for other languages and prevent them from participating. Languages can very different from what you're used to: functional, minimalist, graphical, untyped, strongly typed, and weird in many ways.

Examples of loaded phrases:

- "write a function that"
- "return a pointer to"
- "if the input is invalid, throw an exception"
- "at compile time"
- "you may not use the + operator."
- "if they are of different types"
- "modify the input object"

Usually, this can be fixed by using broader terms, but is sometimes is a sign of a problem with the challenge itself. Consider defining the requirements in terms of input and output without reference to the program internals.

Comment: The "write a function that" should be replaced by "write a program or function that" in most challenges.

Comment: @user81655 I feel like saying `yes`, but I can't think of any examples. However, there are programming languages such as `ES6` where it is golfier to create a function than a program.

Comment: Or Java 8...the boilerplate

Answer (score 76):

### Bonuses in code golf

[Digital Trauma wrote an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8102/20260) about this, but I have harsher views on bonuses, so I'm posting to let people vote separately.

---

Bonuses in code golf say things like "-30% of your byte count if your code can handle any number of strings, not just two." From what I've seen, they range from slightly improving the challenge to seriously harming it. I haven't seen a bonus that totally made a question, but I've seen ones that ruined it. If you do include a bonus, be confident that it makes the question better.

Too often bonuses come from avoiding a hard decision about your challenge. Cutting is hard, so you preserve a weaker or extraneous part of the challenge. Or, you can't decide the scope, so you try to have it both ways. The weak parts might be underspecified, poorly received in the Sandbox, tangential to the rest of the task, or make the spec too cluttered. Don't sweep them into a bonus -- delete them without mercy! Conversely, if you do include a bonus, make sure it as at least as strong as the rest of the challenge.

---

Bonuses are only interesting when they pose a trade-off that could go either way. It's hard to balance, and often a bonus turns out completely unviable or completely mandatory for the language I'm golfing in. A flat bonus (-20 bytes) means much more in a golfing language than Java, and a multiplicative bonus (-30%) depends on the language's degree of boilerplate and its well-suitedness the bonus relative to the main challenge. Sometimes there's no number that works for everything.

When the bonuses are well-balanced, you can have the opposite problem that a golfer needs to write a bunch of different variants of the program to see what's worth in, which becomes exponentially more cumbersome with more and more bonuses.

Comment: [Case in point](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68667/194). Having solved the core problem, I then had to golf *three* output formats to see which would give the lowest score. That was nowhere near as interesting as the core problem.

Comment: I definitely prefer this harsher version. Bonuses nearly always make me feel like I'm reading the answers to two or more separate challenges jumbled together on the same page.

Comment: *exponentially more cumbersome* Exactly! If a challenge has **n** independent bonuses, there are **2ⁿ** different ways to combine them. One bonus is bad enough IMHO, three or more are a disaster.

Comment: Actually I've seen case where bonus save raw bytes. Rarely but there is

Answer (score 75):

## Changing the challenge in the comments

If something was unspecified in your challenge, or if you've decided to make a change to the challenge (Such as to close a loophole), don't just leave a comment. These are often not visible unless you click on the correct button, and will lead to people getting confused.

Instead, edit the challenge to incorporate the change/clarification.

Appropriate solution:

Edit the change/clarification into the question.

Answer (score 74):

### Do X without Y

This isn't always bad, but it's been a particular trap for beginners, so be careful.

In the past, there were popular questions about doing a simple task but with the obvious method banned:

- [Produce the number 2014 without any numbers in your source code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code)
- [How to write a C program for multiplication without using the * and + operators?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/how-to-write-a-c-program-for-multiplication-without-using-the-and-operators)
- [Add without addition (or any of the 4 basic arithmetic operators)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20996/20260)

These have fallen out of favor because they inspired many copycats that basically came down to the same tricks. In general, if your challenge is too simple to be interesting, it won't be saved by banning things. It's better to make the challenge meatier instead.

Also, it's hard to define "without Y" for a wide class of languages, leading to nitpicking like "I'm not using `a+b`, just `sum(a,b)`".

"Do X without Y" can be [good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source?sort=votes&pageSize=50) questions, but I've found the odds stacked sorely against them, especially for new posters, so be careful. Look at past questions and check that yours requires novel ideas, and beware that site standards have gotten much more stringent over time.

Comment: I updated the [restricted-source tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/restricted-source/info) with a disclaimer similar to this a while back.

Answer (score 71):

### Explicitly disallowing or disadvantaging arbitrary (classes of) languages

This has become much rarer recently, but the occasional challenge by a new user still includes it, so here as an answer to point them to.

Disallowing arbitrary languages (or classes of languages, primarily things like "no golfing languages allowed") is not in the spirit of this community, as has been discussed many times on meta. If you don't like golfing languages beating others, a) don't pose a code golf challenge or b) look at the challenge as a separate competition in each language.

This answer also encompasses penalties that only apply to certain languages.

Suggested course of action: (for voters)

- Downvote to discourage this behaviour and show that it is not welcome in this community.
- Leave a friendly comment that this is not how we roll and link them here.
- *Don't* edit it out without the author's permission - I don't think we have a consensus that such restrictions are disallowed or off-topic. They're just a bad idea.

A milder form of this is challenges where the task depends on the language name (e.g. "print the language name"). Those give a byte-count penalty to languages with long names. If this is necessary for the challenge to make sense/be fun, a better idea might be to subtract the language's name from the byte count and require that it appears verbatim in the source code (without the latter requirement, you'd be giving a penalty to languages with *short* names instead).

This answer does *not* encompass challenges which are impossible in some (or many) languages due to technical limitations (audio output, file system manipulation etc.). That said, challenges should strive to be as inclusive as possible without damaging the core of the challenge (do submissions really have to play the audio directly via the speakers, or could they also write an audio file to STDOUT?).

When the OP needs to run all submissions on their own machine (e.g. for [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) or certain [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)s), it's also fine to require that all languages have a freely available compiler or interpreter. I wouldn't call that "arbitrary" restriction. (Whereas, I would call it arbitrary if someone imposed the same restriction on a standard code golf where the OP isn't planning to test every answer on their own machine anyway.)

Comment: I would make an exception for requiring languages that have a freely available compiler/interpreter (so that the OP can test the answers)

Comment: @aditsu Especially true for [tag:king-of-the-hill] puzzles

Comment: @aditsu I think such a limitation isn't an "arbitrary" class of languages, but I'll clarify that. ;)

Comment: Well, I plan to test every answer even for standard code golf.

Comment: @aditsu I think in that case it's viable to let someone else test it who has the language. For code golf it's not necessary that all entries are tested on the same machine. Otherwise, we'd essentially be banning proprietary languages completely.

Comment: I agree with this for the most part but disallowing golfing languages is not arbitrary. They are practically cheating and skew votes in their favor on challenges so they aren't "arbitrary" and I can understand very well why someone would want to disallow them

Comment: @Downgoat I fail to see how they are cheating, but this comment thread is probably the wrong place for this discussion.

Comment: I was initially resistant to golfing languages, but then I realized they're simply a different way to enjoy the puzzle. If you create a puzzle and intend for it to be solved in Java, C# or something and some eso-lang fiend writes a program shorter than the language name to solve it, that doesn't make your puzzle any less fun! Also, if it is so easily solved, perhaps it wasn't quite as interesting as originally thought?

Comment: Specifically, what made me change my mind was a game called Kittens. I like Kittens and it's fun to play. But I have a wife and two kids, so I don't get much time to play. So I play it with the game paused and manually pass the time using Javascript - this way I can simulate hours at a time (although I greatly enjoy the micromanagement aspect, so it's usually minutes at a time.) The original creator thinks this is cheating - I think it's simply a different way to play. I think the same thing applies here - it's just a different way to play.

Comment: Something to note: for the example of tasks that depend on the programming language's name requiring that the language's name appears verbatim in the source code is a disadvantage to languages that do not have string literals (such as brainfuck or Brain-Flak) or impossible in others whose source code is not text (like Piet). Another way of handling is allowing the programs to take their language name from stdin.

Comment: @0                            ' When you do that, the challenge is no longer dependent on the language's name, so that's fine of course.

Comment: If you dislike golfing languages, the best thing to do is to ask for something they can't do. Most golfing languages have a tiny set of built-ins and standard libraries, while languages like Java and Mathematica have a broad range of tools. If your challenge requires something real languages have a std lib for but golfing languages don't, I doubt, despite their beautiful conciseness, that golfing languages can write a lib in fewer characters than you can import one.

Comment: I recently asked to compress the periodic table, and excluded the use of built-in periodic tables. Got quite some comments on it...

Comment: I disagree. Disallowing arbitrary languages is already common. In a challenge that outputs or analyzes an image, you have basically excluded textual IO only challenge. Another way a challenge may disallow arbitrary languages is that the challenge is showcasing certain features, like dependent typing. For example: given a function f : P(A) -> P(A) and proof that a being a subset of b implies f(a) being a subset of f(b), prove the existence of x a subset of X so that f(x) = x. You wouldn't be able to solve it in python or 05AB1E, as you actually needs a theorem prover.

Answer (score 63):

## Putting test cases in a hard to use format

Supplying test cases is always a good idea, but people are more likely to use them (and thus have better tested code) if they can easily be copied and pasted into a test suite.

So format your test cases as simply and as consistently as possible, preferably in a single code block. If you have lots of test cases and you want to section them out by type, put empty lines between sections instead of using several separate code blocks.

**Be sure to include any examples used during explanation as test cases. People  may otherwise forget important examples while focusing on test cases.**

## Do This:

```
Input -> Output
cat -> kitten
dog -> puppy
seal -> pup
bear -> cub
cow -> calf
bird -> chick
echidna -> puggle
```

Replace `->` with something else if the `-` and `>` might get confused with the input and output. Don't use `→` (right arrow) or other Non-ASCII since not all languages/compilers may allow it.

## DON'T Do This:

```
+---------+--------+
|  Input  | Output |
+---------+--------+
| cat     | kitten |
| dog     | puppy  |
| seal    | pup    |
| bear    | cub    |
| cow     | calf   |
| bird    | chick  |
| echidna | puggle |
+---------+--------+
```

Yes, it looks nicer, but it's more hassle to get the pure data.

## DON'T Do This:

The inputs `cat`, `dog` `seal`, `bear`, `cow`, `bird`, and `echidna` have the respective outputs `kitten`, `puppy`, `pup`, `cub`, `calf`, `chick`, and `puggle`.

## DON'T Do This:

The input

```
cat
```

has output

```
kitten
```

The input

```
dog
```

has output

```
puppy
```

Likewise, the input

```
seal
```

has output

```
pup
```

and the input

```
bear
```

has output

```
cub
```

and the input

```
cow
```

has output

```
calf
```

and the input

```
bird
```

has output

```
chick
```

and, finally, the input

```
echidna
```

has output

```
puggle
```

---

<sup>Yes, I have been guilty of this. No, I am not going to fix all my old challenges.</sup>

Comment: The ASCII art table isn't too bad I think. If you just copy out the lines that actually contain test cases the format is about as easy to transform as the `->` format.

Comment: @MartinBüttner But there are two extra `|` dividers and an unknown number of spaces to deal with. Not everyone here knows regex and may rely on `strip`'s and `split`'s and the like, which is more cumbersome with the table.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Related chat-challenge/poll: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26850192#26850192

Comment: in fact, I even prefer the `->` format with the arrows aligned. I think that's the best compromise between human readability and being easy to process into something your code can deal with.

Comment: <kbd>.Header 1. </kbd><kbd>.Header 2. </kbd><kbd>.Header 3.</kbd><br/>
<kbd>.Cell 1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><kbd>.Cell 2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><kbd>.Cell 3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><br/>
<kbd>.Cell 4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><kbd>.Cell 5.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><kbd>.Cell 6.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd><br/> Modified from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128302). Pain to type, looks pretty, easy to copy/paste into Calc or something. Can change dots to quotes or whatever.

Comment: Of late I've given example inputs [like this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75152/volts-amps-watts-and-ohms-given-two-calculate-the-other-two).  bad? ok? good? better?

Comment: Only if there were tables..

Comment: +1 for monotremes.

Answer (score 59):

### Chameleon challenges

Chameleon challenges look like they're about one thing but are really about another. In doing the challenge, most of the effort is spent on something peripheral. Fix this by being honest about your challenge in the title and description, or by simplifying or removing the non-core parts.

Some causes of chameleon challenges:

- Requiring a [cumbersome input/output format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260) that takes more effort to process than the challenge itself
- Requiring that malformed inputs are detected and specially handled.
- In code golf, having long fixed output strings that benefit from compression.
- [Including bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/20260) that are so large that any competitive answer must do them.
- Scoring a challenge on a small set of test cases where it's more effective to hardcode the outputs or overfit them than to actually do the task.
- Scoring by fraction right on a test battery where it's not hard to get 100% right, making the tiebreak the real score.
- Scoring by a combination of two factors, like length and effectiveness, in a way that one contribution is much larger than the other.

Comment: I'd like to note that we actually have (and support) a large number of chameleon challenges on PPCG:  There are many challenges where the task is the "difficult" part, and attaching the [tag:code-golf] is simply to make it fit our standards.  Ideally we'd prefer these challenges to have a different scoring method, but that doesn't always work out.

Answer (score 59):

### Requiring minimum scores

In short, don't post a code golf that says "Your code has to be shorter than 100 bytes" (the same applies to any other winning criterion). The usual motivation is that the author found some code somewhere and challenges people to beat the score of that code. That's a fine motivation for a challenge, but actually requiring all answers to be better than that benchmark is incredibly detrimental to the challenge. It doesn't increase competition between answers that are better than the requirement. But it does disallow answers which are worse than the limit but might contain interesting ideas which the better answers could also benefit from, and it also rules out some languages entirely which are simply incapable of beating the given score. There's also the possibility that you've set the limit too low and made the challenge impossible. Additionally, most often answers aren't originally posted with the best possible score, but are later improved because other people give suggestions. This would be impossible if the first attempt wasn't allowed to be posted.

Most importantly though, all that a minimum score is saying is "if you're not good enough, you can't participate", which I think is plainly rude.

Comment: +1, but if an author really wanted a score threshold, I would be OK with answers that do not meet the score threshold being allowed but being marked as not competitive.

Comment: On the other hand, a minimum score may be a reasonable threshold for defining what qualifies as a serious contender. For example, on my [latest challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77510/45941), I would consider submissions that do not have positive scores to not be serious contenders, because they failed the basic premise of the challenge (optimize the output length).

Comment: _"the same applies to any other winning criterion"_ - what about program should terminate in one minute for input less than smth?

Comment: @Qwertiy That depends on the challenge. If it's a code golf, adding that as a validity criterion is fine, because it's not related to the scoring and only ensures efficient solutions. If it's a code-challenge/fastest-code along the lines of "scored by largest input you can handle in one minute", then that's also fine because time is not a variable that goes into scoring. But if you have a fastest code that says "fastest code wins, but you must be faster than one minute" you're back to saying "if you're not good enough you can't participate".

Comment: @MartinBüttner, but if some code executes 24 hours eating 100% of processor, are you really going to wait until it finishes? I mean, there should be some reasonable limit on time. By the way, about limit on length: the answer length is limited by 30K chars, so you can't post the anser longer than that.

Comment: @Qwertiy Probably not, because it's going to be beaten by a faster submission anyway, so it's exact score is irrelevant. If I designed the challenge such that all answers will take more than 24 hours, that's really my own fault, and requiring them to be faster than 1 minute isn't actually going to *make* them faster. Also with such an extreme difference, there's a good chance that the slow answer is intentionally slow which makes it invalid as not trying to compete (as per the help centre).

Comment: @Mego You're right that in your case having a negative score clearly makes it not a serious contender, but that's obvious for everyone to see and doesn't need an explicit rule. I think it's quite rare that there's such a clear cut-off as in your case, and in all other cases I'd rather have the community decide which answers are serious contenders and which aren't, instead of letting the OP guess an arbitrary threshold.

Comment: @Qwertiy Re, answer length limit. You sure can (and we've had answers whose length was given in scientific notation), provided you can describe how the code is generated. Just think of Unary answers. There's no point (and it's impossible) to actually include the code in the answer, but all you need to know is how many `0`s the program has.

Comment: Can I say "lowest code length+running time(sec) win, at most 1000 char, at most 10 min"?

Answer (score 52):

### Non-observable program requirements

The validity of a program should depend on things that can be observed when the program is treated as a black box. Examples are data written to standard output or error streams, drawing on the screen, file operations, memory usage, and runtime. *Non*-observable behaviors include "string operations" and "implementing the Fu-Barr algorithm". Additionally, "using Y" would fall into the non-observable category in most instances of "Do X without Y"

#### Why they are bad

Non-observable requirements tend to be vague, subjective, or based on false assumptions about the properties of programming languages. For example, requiring that answers use a specific algorithm is highly open to interpretation. What modifications are allowed? Can some steps be replaced with different operations that produce the same result?

#### Exceptions

A commonly used non-observable requirement is to avoid using a library function that solves the entire challenge. I believe these rules are OK. Like other non-observable requirements, one can find borderline cases of whether a built-in function solves all of the task or not, but the benefits of higher-quality answers outweigh the costs.

Comment: Would you consider the usual definition of truthiness to be unobservable?

Comment: I agree with everything except the exception. I think this answer is a good reason to avoid excluding library functions.

Comment: @xnor Yes, that's a good example of making false assumptions about the programming language. It falsely assumes that every language has "if" statements.

Comment: Note that if you want to force the use of a particular algorithm, you can normally do it observably by requesting that program prints out the intermediate steps of the algorithm.

Comment: What a strange consensus. That a programming language actually be a programming language as per **_"A purported programming language should be accepted as such if and only if it is capable of addition of natural numbers and primality testing of natural numbers,"_** seems to be a non-observable requirement. What about [tag:restricted-source]? One could even argue that _code length_ a la [Starry Night](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69930) is a non-observable requirement.

Comment: @primo I don't understand. Length of a source code and what characters it includes are things which can quite easily be measured.

Comment: if you're willing to examine the code, i.e. not treat it as a "black box", then yes.

Comment: Some of the most interesting challenges I have seen have placed constraints on the source code, such as not using certain characters. There was one that required writing X number of different expressions in your language, where no character could be used in more than one expression. It was awesome.

Comment: @SteveBennett I don't think this answer is talking about [tag:restricted-source]. By "Non-observable program requirements", I think they mean things like the algorithm used, rather than the actual, literal, byte values of the source code. The reason non-observable requirements are often bad is that they assume features of a language, which restricting bytes/characters does not do, or are difficult to objectively judge (i.e., how far you stray from an algorithm), unlike the byte length or contents of the program.

Comment: This will exclude computational complexity based challenge, which is much more interesting than just input-output. Most language also allows reasoning about how long a program could take modulo addition/multiplication by a constant.

Answer (score 51):

### Don't allow / ask for different things in languages with different capabilities

Don't write specs like "Do X. If your language doesn't support X, you can do Y instead". Examples are:

- Do some math in floating point. If your language doesn't support floating point, you can use integer
- Read input from a file. If your language doesn't support file I/O, you can read from stdin

X and Y, can be quite different tasks, although they might look similar. Either allow the alternatives Y for all languages or for none.

Comment: Full support on this one. A compromise that I've found can be effective is "Do X. If your language cannot do X, you can do Y instead, but the submission will be non-competing".

Comment: I strongly agree with this answer. I'm not a fan of non-competing submissions. If it doesn't fit the challenge, it should be posted elsewhere.

Comment: If a language cannot do X, I don't see any reason to try to include that language.  We've got plenty of other challenges that language can compete in.

Comment: @trichoplax I don't mind non-competing submissions if they're non-competing because the language came after the challenge, and the language wasn't obviously designed to solve the challenge well.

Comment: @Mego Yes I agree about languages post dating the challenge. I just don't like solutions that solve a different challenge (or challenges that invite this).

Comment: I disagree. The whole point of this question https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1 is exactly to allow different things in language with different capabilities. Otherwise, any question that asks an input will be unable to be answered using /// because injecting the source code is the only way to input in ///, but we don't want hardcoding in other languages.

Answer (score 45):

## "Ideally, your code will..."

Avoid recommended features in your spec. If it's not mandatory, answers won't do it. The goal is to write the shortest/fastest/winningest code that still satisfies the requirements, however minimally, so any features that can be cut or simplified will be.

Of course, popularity contests are an exception.

Comment: Even worse: "Ideally, your code will...; -10% bonus for that feature".

Comment: @TrangOul that's a separate thing to avoid, stated higher up.

Answer (score 44):

## Arbitrarily overriding the defaults

The default [code formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/20260), [input/output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/20260), and other defaults are a product of community thought and discussion. Don't change them just because you feel like it or disagree with them. They have good reasons for being as they are, some of which are only apparent for specific languages that would otherwise be unusable or cumbersome or require ad-hoc rulings.

Only override the defaults when they don't serve their purpose because of some specific feature of your challenge, and even then think if you can make the challenge accommodate instead.

Comment: I'd like to note that, from my experience, this doesn't typically apply to KOTH challenges.

Answer (score 44):

## Saying you should produce one or several outputs *randomly* without further specification

### One random output

Say someone writes a challenge about generating a labyrinth of a given size (width and height) taken as input, and they say that you should create a *randomly arranged labyrinth* of that size.

What does *random* mean here? As it has been specified, you may very well create two possible labyrinths that comform to the size specs and pick randomly between the two. Or even create just one and claim it is [random](http://xkcd.com/221/).

As it stands, the challenge is not well specified. **Just saying *random* means nothing**. The **probability distribution** needs to be indicated. Some correct specifications would be (these are excluding alternatives):

1. *All possible labyrinths of the given size should be produced with the same probability*;
2. *All possible labyrinths of the given size should have a nonzero probability of occurrence*;
3. *The code should be able to produce at least 10 different labyrinths of the given size, each with nonzero probability*.

Option 1 corresponds to a uniform distribution, which is "as random as it gets" (but may be too demanding for certain challenges). Option 2 is more flexible on the answerer, and is probably a good default. With option 3, the challenge writer should be careful to check that it is always possible to generate at least 10 valid outputs.

### Several random outputs

The problem is aggravated when there are several random pieces (numbers, characters, etc) that need to be produced. Consider for example a challenge that takes a string as input and asks to *introduce a random printable ASCII character after each character of the input string*.

First off, the same considerations as above apply (Can I choose from just "a", "b", "c" as my random characters? Do I need to pick among those characters with the same probability?). But in this case there's the additional problem of **statistical relationship** between the random outputs. Can I randomly pick a character and insert that *same* character in all required positions? Or do the inserted characters need to be *independently* picked?

To avoid this ambiguity, the possible relationship between the randomly generated pieces needs to be specified in the challenge. In more proper terms, the **joint probability distribution** of the random pieces needs to be specified. Sorry if it sounds a little complicated, but this is necessary.

If you are not sure and want to keep things simple, after having specified the distribution of each piece (as discussed above) you can say that the random pieces should be statistically independent. This means that each piece should be randomly generated without regard of the random choices that were made/will be made for the other pieces.

### Bottomline

The point is to **properly specify "randomness"**. Don't rely on "common sense" or assume that answerers will adhere to the "spirit" of the challenge. Your *that's against the spirit of the challenge* may very well be someone else's *clever trick that saved me a few bytes*.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/14215), but not exactly overlapping.

Comment: I've now added a [definition for uniform](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10923/20283) on that meta post too.

Comment: @trichoplax Good point, and well explained there

Comment: "Your *that's against the spirit of the challenge* may very well be someone else's *clever trick that saved me a few bytes.*" This is a strong argument for clear, objective rules and specifications everywhere.

Answer (score 43):

### Requiring the use of unnecessarily "complicated" number types

A large proportion of our challenges deal with numbers, or lists of numbers. An important consideration is always what sort of numbers are valid input (positive integers, non-negative integers, all integers, floating-point numbers, complex integers, complex floating-point numbers...).

In the interest of making the challenge accessible to (and enjoyable in) the widest range of languages, **try making the number types as simple as possible without harming the challenge.**

If your challenge is about sorting a list of numbers, positive integers suffice. Using floating point numbers doesn't add anything interesting to the challenge but makes it incredibly tough or practically impossible to solve the challenge in languages that only support integer data, even though they might be able to solve the actual task of sorting quite easily.

In some cases, the actual values are completely arbitrary and only exist as place holders in the structure of an array. In this case you can even consider restricting the input to single-digit integers, unless you want to specifically make string-processing based approaches less feasible.

Of course, some challenges only make sense for floating point numbers or even complex floating-point, and that's completely fine. But when the core of the challenge is not about handling those data types, they only distract from the interesting parts.

As a rule of thumb I propose that people ask "if I change this from integer to float or vice-versa, would this affect any viable approaches in mainstream languages?" If that's the case, then requiring floating point might make sense (if those are the approaches you're looking for). But if not, limiting the challenge to integers won't do it any harm for the common languages, and will make the challenge more interesting to people who prefer to use esolangs for a little extra challenge.

Answer (score 38):

### Using shortest code as a tie-breaking winning criterion in [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) questions

In challenges such as [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69920/45941), there is nothing stopping users from copying another answer's solution, implementing it in a terser language, and posting it as a separate answer. The user therefore would receive the same score for their submission and win the tie-breaker, despite the original user doing the lion's share of the work and being more deserving of winning.

Using earliest submission as the tie-breaking criterion avoids this problem entirely.

Comment: *cough, cough* [Yeah, or as part of the primary winning criterion in the first place](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75256/good-old-suffix-vector) *hack, cough*

Comment: @tac Isn't length of code the primary criterion in all [tag:code-golf]s?

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ We're talking about [tag:code-challenge] here

Comment: @tac [Are we?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8690/43319)

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ It literally says code challenge in bold at the top of the answer.

Comment: @​Mego I know, but @tac was probably referring to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75256/good-old-suffix-vector?noredirect=1#comment183246_75256).

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ That is a code challenge, not code golf, so it's relevant.

Comment: But, but... My point was exactly that my challenge *is* a code-golf. Community just wouldn't let me tag it that way. I think it is strange to complain that there is length scoring one something I *wanted* to be tagged code golf, even though the community changed the tagging. In other words, my tagging and scoring system were consistent!

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ No, it wasn't consistent. This isn't the proper place to have this discussion. If you are still confused as to why your challenge was not code golf, consult the tag wiki, and ask any questions in chat or in a separate meta question.

Comment: I agree with this. Any tie breaker which is also an additional challenge distracts from the main objective and causes the same additional work as bonuses.

Comment: I'd like to offer [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118150/) as a counterexample where the tie-breaker felt entirely natural. I think it helped that the main score was *sort of* length-based and very tied to the specific language used.

Comment: I think there are some counter arguments to this.  First, recall that answers are always to be judged *per* language. Second, in any normal challenge it is always open to someone to copy an answer into another language or simply tweak the existing answer a little . They just might not get upvoted much,   Third, if there is an optimal answer and the tie breaker is the first answer then that question is effectively closed forever which is not ideal.

Answer (score 37):

### Allowing standard loopholes in general

Don't say "[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/20260) are allowed". They ban silly things like [making up a language where the solution is a single character](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/20260) or just [printing the string "the answer"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/20260). Even if you find these amusing, we got tired of them long ago and that's why they're forbidden.

Allowing specific loopholes, such as [fetching the output from an external source](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/20198) can and should be overriden if it makes the challenge better.  For example, if the challenge is about getting information from a website, then it should definitely be allowed.  This answer addresses allowing standard loopholes in general, as they apply to most challenges.

Comment: I'd argue that it's worth removing the allowance from the challenge completely, even if the author wants it to stay. We as a community have overwhelmingly voted to disallow the standard loopholes across the site, so one user should not be able to override that strong consensus.

Comment: Broadly allowing standard loopholes is a bad idea, but we frequently have good challenges that allow a single loophole.  For example, [Fetching the desired output from an external source](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/20198) has been "overriden" a couple of times, such as for [Automate the OEIS](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89376/automate-the-oeis)

Answer (score 37):

## The prime numbers

We have [226 questions about prime numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) at the time of writing. Almost every single one of these involves some adaptation of the “canonical prime checking code” or the “canonical prime generator”. Primes are notorious for not really conforming to any mathematical symmetry in a lot of ways, so very often, there is no way around a “brute force” approach: you just do exactly what the challenge tells you to do with your bit of primality logic; and that bit of logic is usually the “ungolfable” part.

I beg you — I *plead* you — consider *any* other integer sequence for once. Spice things up! Whatever challenge you were going to write called “Onerous primes” or “Highfalutin primes” or “Supercalifragilistic primes”: ask it about the [odious numbers](http://oeis.org/A000069) or the [lucky numbers](https://oeis.org/A000959) or the [Ulam numbers](https://oeis.org/A002858) instead. Or heck, ask it about the [squares](https://oeis.org/A000290)!

There isn’t anything wrong with the prime numbers, but there isn’t anything *particularly* nice about them either. In fact, primality is quite an “ugly” condition, in the sense that there are no formulas for the next prime after \$p\$, or the number of primes below \$n\$, etc. This is what makes them interesting to study from a mathematical point of view, but they’re a nuisance to compute things about, because you can’t apply very many tricks, and this might actually *limit* the set of approaches golfers could reasonably take to solve your challenge with.

Please, give this some thought before you post the 227th, or 228th, or 229th question asking us to find “the n-th prime number such that (blah blah blah).”

Comment: Shouldn't there at least be a prime number of such challenges?

Comment: I disagree that there aren't many tricks to use. As someone who has done quite a bit of Project Euler I can tell you there are a lot of interesting shortcuts (many involving totient function, Möbius inversion, prime-counting algorithm)

Comment: There are many shortcuts in speed, but rarely ever in code size.

Comment: Wouldn't the primes be good for proposing fastest-algorithm challenges tho?

Answer (score 37):

## Formulating the challenge as *something* and then including a *twist* that completely changes the task

Don't hide information from the reader. Don't enounce the challenge as something that later on it will turn out not to be.

To ellaborate, consider the following formulation:

> *Do* < *task **A**, usually easy, described in one or several paragraphs* >
>
> *But wait!* / *Not so fast!* / *There is a twist*...
>
> *You can only use ...* < *clarification that significantly changes the task into **B*** >

This is **misleading**. The initial description says something, then the challenge turns out to be something else.

A typical use of this is to present the task as deceivingly simple (A), and then clarify that it is actually much harder (B). The writer's intention may be to make the challenge more "fun" or to add some "spice". But it's better to **be honest from the start** and include all the relevant information at the beginning, not leaving important information for later. The "twist" may be fun for the writer; but the reader may feel they have been deceived. What was initially told is not really true.

I'm not saying that clarifications are not allowed. As the challenge text progresses, the initial description can (should) be refined. But **don't include a significant change in the middle of the text**. If a "clarification" contradicts or significantly alters the challenge, it should be put right at the outset (it's not a clarification, it's one of the main ideas).

The order of ideas in the text should be chosen to **minimize surprise** to the reader. Start with the main ideas, then include refinements that modify or qualify any previous statements as little as possible.

Comment: I disagree. I do this quite often as part of my writing style.

Comment: +1. This is the first rule of technical writing. While misdirection is acceptable for creative writing, it's not acceptable for technical writing. We aim for our challenges to be as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: Whether or not twists are acceptable is largely determined by how it is explained.  If the twist is explained early on, or if explaining the twist depends on everything above it, then that's acceptable.  **You want to get to the core (the twist) of the challenge as fast as possible**.  Don't waste reader's time.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I agree with you, except on terminology. _If the twist is explained early on_... then it's not a _twist_. By _twist_ I mean something that contradicts or significantly changes the previous information (i.e. as per a definition [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_twist))

Comment: I agree.  However, given your short example above, it appears like your twist appears as the second sentence, so I want to make it clear that that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @NathanMerrill The first item in the example (as well as the third) was meant to represent more than a sentence; usually one or several paragraphs. I've clarified that

Comment: This can be avoided by giving a description of the pre-"twist" challenge but not phrasing it as if this is actually the problem to be solved.
 [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147274/61384) (one of my challenges)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Yes, that's a good way to word it, because it doesn't try to fool the reader

Comment: I don't agree with this. Twists are fine, as long as they're adequately described. It's only a problem if a massive constraint is buried in an obscure bullet point and easily missed.

Answer (score 36):

### Most kinds of generalised quines

Quines continue to fascinate this community... but we already have a plain quine challenge so we're "forced" to innovate by making quine-related challenges that aren't pure quines. For the purpose of this post, I'm defining a generalised quine as a program `P` which prints `F(P)`, where `F` is some function of a string. (E.g. "print the reverse of your source code" would have a string reversal function as `F`.)

Just to be clear, this answer does not apply to other extensions of quines, like putting extra restrictions on them, as in a radiation-hardened quine, or extending them to mutual quines etc. This is purely about "print this transformation of your source code" challenges.

The problem with many of these is that there is no other solution than a) take your language's standard quine to get your source code as a string, b) tack on an implementation of `F`. If that's the case, the quine part doesn't add anything interesting - there's no better technique than copying "half" your solution from an established quine. In that case there's two possibilities: `F` itself is boring or has been done before, in which case the challenge doesn't add anything interesting at all, or `F` itself is actually an interesting string processing task, in which case it should be posted as such, without wrapping it in a quine framework.

That doesn't mean all generalised quines are bad. Some *do* admit interesting shortcuts than don't require the full standard quine to be reproduced. Before posting a generalised quine challenge, you should ask yourself whether that's possible or not.

Answer (score 35):

### Adding unnecessary fluff

*See also: [Chameleon challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/21487), [Cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/21487), [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/21487)*

What's the main point of the challenge? Try to keep the challenge to just that. Don't go adding frills to the challenge just because it "looks too easy", or inserting strange modifications to a perfectly okay challenge just to "make things interesting". Keep it lean and straight to the point.

In addition to the related posts above, here are more examples of what not to do (when there's no good alternative approaches):

- Combining two or more unrelated core challenges into one — consider splitting the challenge up into separate challenges or dropping unnecessary parts. Examples include:

  - Instead of simply summing a list of numbers `n` at the end, requiring answers to sum over some unnecessary transformation (e.g.`n^2`, `n+1`, `n`th Fibonacci number) instead.
  - Instead of simply applying a function `f(x)` to a list of inputs, adding an unnecessary filtering step before the function is applied (e.g. median of only the prime numbers in the input).
- Unnecessary extra applications, e.g. instead of calculating a single function `f(x)`:

  - Making answers calculate `f(x)` for every `x` in a list.
  - Making answers take an additional parameter `n` and applying `f` to the input `x`, `n` times.
  - Making answers calculate `x-f(x)` until the result is 1, then counting how many steps that took.

Comment: The last two bullet points are debatable, especially when `f` is simple, since there may be (more or less obvious) shortcuts. [Case in point.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79841/32014)

Comment: @Zgarb The emphasis was meant to be on "when there's no good alternative approaches" :) (I should probably add that the only reason they're there is because there's been such examples in the past)

Comment: I think it's a "don't just combine two challenges"? (assuming some basic challenges were there for long time)

Answer (score 33):

### Patching out approaches

On your challenge, someone posts a solution that's cheap and not at all what you intended. You [have the option to change the rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7786/20260), but do so very carefully as there's many pitfalls.

**Don't:**

- *Criticize the answerer.* They were just trying their best towards the winning criteria as stated.
- *[Simply encourage avoiding this approach](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8066/20260).* If it's not against the rules, it's fair game.
- *Ban answers "not in the spirit of the challenge".* Answerers can't read your mind to infer your intentions.
- *Require using a certain method.* A lot of the fun is in finding novel, unexpected approaches.
- *Attack the symptoms.* If the exploit suggests a broader problem with the challenge, fix that problem. Also, it's often hard to [specify exactly what is off-limits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260).
- *Make rash changes.* These might introduce other problems. It's hard to think clearly under time pressure. If you're unsure, ask that the challenge be closed, post it in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/20260) to get feedback, and reopen it when it's in good shape.
- *Post changes [solely in the comments.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/20260)*

Answer (score 32):

## Input Validation

This is a subset of [adding special cases for completeness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13290/76162) that seems to come up pretty often. From a given set of possible inputs, a solution shouldn't have to sort out inputs that don't apply to the challenge.

For example, imagine a challenge that asks to find the index of a value in a sequence. For values that are not in the sequence, or values that don't apply (strings or floats in an integer sequence):

#### Don't:

- Require printing "Invalid input!" or something similar
- Ask for a specific return value, such as `-1`, `0` or the empty string.

#### Do:

- Say that all inputs are assumed to be valid.
- Allow undefined behaviour
- (Less preferably) the return value should be any value not normally returned by valid inputs. This includes errors, undefined values, etc.

It's not as fun to have to program in a bunch of edge cases testing whether an element is actually in the array or a number is non-negative. Plus having to allocate precious bytes for a string literal "Invalid input" in the middle of your code is unsatisfying and unnecessary.

If your challenge becomes trivial without input validation, then consider making it a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) instead.

Comment: Also note that having to hardcode a string like "Invalid input" gives [even more advantage to golfing languages with compressed strings](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxyT6oe7Oh/ubMk8tPv/fwA).

Comment: The check for allowed input can be golfed too... I not see where is the problem... One has always make in count each routine can fail for bad input in every place

Comment: The issue is that it turns one challenge into two tasks. If a particular format is interesting to validate, then maybe it deserves to have its own challenge so a clever solution for using the input isn't held back by having to validate it and a clever solution for validating it isn't held back by having to use it. Imagine if solutons [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109043/count-my-change) had to ensure that each coin is a quarter, dime, nickel or penny--there'd barely be a use for the ninth-character hack at all!

Answer (score 28):

### Popularity Contests

[Popularity contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info), while allowed, are heavily disfavored by site culture. You're likely better off reworking your challenge to use an [objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305/20260) that isn't votes, such as [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) or [fastest code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info). That is, unless you're an experienced user who knows when to disregard such advice.

Of the [last 15 pop-cons as of writing, 11 have been closed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest?sort=newest&pageSize=15). If you're a newish user, chances are yours will be too. I'm not claiming bias, but that one needs a very good feel of the community to navigate the minefield of pop-cons, and that takes time to develop.

Most pop cons are closed as "too broad" for having "too many possible answers". Saying "do [simple task] in a creative way" won't cut it -- pop-cons needs an exact, specific task that is hard to solve, and whose solutions can be further evaluated by human criteria.  Even with this, I'd advise new-ish users to avoid pop-cons altogether, since it's easy to mess up and might be closed or downvoted anyway.

Comment: It should be noted that part of the reason they are received poorly is because of the "fastest gun in the west" effect.

Comment: To emphasize the point here for future viewers: **Pop-cons should *not* be unconditionally avoided. It's just that new users will likely have better luck writing other types of challenges (namely code-golf).**

Comment: -1 popularity contests are not inherently bad, but rather the challenge in and of itself. Many of the top questions on this sight are popularity contests. SImply the question spec should be tight, and allow variation and objective human  judging

Comment: They're allowed, but will be closed, convert them to golf... Or at least that's been my experience.

Comment: New users should put challenges in the sandbox, since there is a chance they have a good pop-con.

Answer (score 26):

### Pointless links

Links pointing to [relevant information](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/45941) that aid in understanding the challenge are good. Links that point to information that is [common knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck) or [irrelevant to the challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) are not. They [distract the reader](https://xkcd.com/214/), and can lead to [dozens of tabs being opened at once](http://www.xkcd.com/609/).

If a challenge is posted with useless links, edit them out. It doesn't actively harm the challenge in any way.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the informative duck link. It really helped shine a light on what you're saying here, and the answer would be less convincing without it.

Comment: This sounds sensible to me. Perhaps also link here so it's not seen as just an arbitrary decision.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is not to say "We should have more pointless links" but just to say "The line between pointful and pointless is subjective". Although there is always going to be disagreement on what counts as relevant, I still think avoiding pointless links is a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Can’t belive I just got rickrolled...

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka That's why I've personally opened the link before. It shows up as already viewed >:D

Answer (score 25):

## Hidden pattern in the output for code golf challenges

You **should not** post a challenge in which an essential part is to find a pattern in the required output, which is not stated in the challenge but which greatly simplifies the code. That kind of challenges are essentially a puzzle in disguise.

As an **example** of a **non-valid** challenge, consider one that simply requires to

> Produce this fixed string:
>
> `bebfjcgfdfijhjdcdiegcgeddidchjfaciiebjhbgjdjjdhfbaficajhejeefjcdahibgeagcigcaijj`

without further explanation. The code will be much shorter if one realizes that the string is the first 80 decimals of `pi` with `0` replaced by `a`, `1` by `b` etc.

The **reasons** why these challenges should be avoided are:

- The actual complexity is in finding a hidden pattern, rather than in coding or programming. This is of little interest on this site, and possibly off-topic (consider posting on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com).
- Once an answer finds out the pattern, all other answers can do the same. If the pattern is going to be eventually known anyway, it is better to describe it upfront in the challenge.

So, you **should** state the pattern in the challenge text. If you feel that makes the challenge "less interesting", consider modifying it in some other way.

Note, however, that the challenge is **not** expected to describe **all** possible characterizations or patterns that the output satisfies. Including one (or maybe several) is enough. There is **no requirement to be exhaustive**.

For **example**, this would be **valid** as a challenge (adding further rules for output format etc):

> Determine if the input is a triangular number, that is, if it can be expressed as `1+2+···+k`, or equivalently as `k*(k+1)/2`, for some positive integer `k`.

The pattern is embodied by the definition of triangular numbers (`1+2+...+k`), which is included in the challenge. The challenge also contains another equivalent characterization (`k*(k+1)/2`). Now, an answer may find and exploit some other characterization, such as

> A positive integer `n` is triangular if and only if `8*n+1` is a square.

It is totally fine if the challenge text does not include that information (which might have even been unknown to the challenge writer).

Comment: Agreed: this is a programming puzzle, which [isn't really a thing here anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/what-should-this-site-be-called-now-that-its-getting-a-design/17645#comment62924_17615). Programming puzzles should do just fine on Puzzling.SE (if they're good), where "first person to solve it" is the culture. This site's culture expects that everyone, even a latecomer, has a chance to solve a challenge (more or less, though if you're not the fastest gun you may find that there are already three answers in your preferred language).

Answer (score 24):

## Narrow references

Beware of challenge topics that tickle your fancy, but others won't appreciate.

- An in-joke among friends
- A reference to a movie you like
- A task from actual code you wrote
- A small part of an existing algorithm without context

These can be sources of inspiration, but make sure the challenge itself is interesting to do. Imagine someone without the background: would they appreciate the topic once you explain it? Often it's best to just pose the task, then unobtrusively explain the background separately.

Comment: Might be an idea to s/movie/creative work/

Answer (score 22):

## Bonuses in code-golf

This might be controversial - Personally I'm not sure which way to go on this one.

---

In most cases, code-golf scoring is simple - shortest answer in bytes wins.

However some questions offer bonuses to reduce scores if certain optional requirements are met.  This necessarily complicates scoring to the possible detriment of the question.  Often this ends up with either negative-score answers or non-integer score answers.  Of course comparisons of such scores are not rocket science, but they do leave a greater margin of error, as well as lower answer readability due to the extra cruft of score calculations.

It can be argued that a well-written challenge can stand alone without the need for bonuses.

---

On the other hand, bonuses can make an question more accessible, both by allowing a larger range of participant ability, and possibly allowing answers in a more diverse set of languages.

Also bonuses add an extra dimension to the golfing process, which can make a problem more interesting to work on.

Comment: I think the complication to the scoring is not even the bad part of bonuses. The problem is that you often have to solve the problem with all possible subsets of bonuses implemented to find out which one actually gives you the lowest score.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes - that's the *extra dimension to the golfing process* I'm talking about - a good or bad thing, depending on your perspective

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but I wanted to add that it's not necessarily an advantage. ;)

Comment: If linking to this, it's worth also considering the [stronger version](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8106#8106), which also currently has more community support

Answer (score 22):

### Using old challenges as a model

Just because an old challenge did something doesn't mean yours should too. Many old challenges wouldn't pass muster nowadays. Don't be surprised if your challenge is downvoted or closed even though a comparable old one is at +87.

Site standards have risen a lot over the years. Challenges are expected to be objective, precisely specified, and comprehensively covered by test cases. Moreover, some formerly-popular types of challenges have fallen out of community favor: [pop cons about creativity](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8134/20260), [pure programming puzzles](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10064/20260), [code golfs with bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/20260), [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260), etc.

For a rough guide, as of this writing (Oct 2016), I'd say 2013 and before is a different world, and things from 2014-2015 are iffy as references.

Also, beware in general of "but this challenge did it!" regardless of the time. It may not have been a good idea for that challenge, and even if it was, it may not be a good idea for yours.

Answer (score 21):

### Tacked-on fixes

If you clarify or modify your challenge after posting, don't just tack on a note to the end or to a list of bullet points. Edit in the change.

It's confusing when the body of the challenge says one thing but a later part says another. Of course, it would be ideal not to change the challenge after posting, but if you have to edit, do so cleanly.

For example, if you said to "take two integers as input", but, when asked, clarify that you had positive integers in mind, don't just add a note at the end that says

> - You may assume the input integers will be positive.

Instead, change the line to "take two positive integers as input".

If you have to make a substantial change, or there's already answers, it might be worth making a note about your change at the end to make people aware of it.

Answer (score 21):

## Excessively long back stories

This is a site for people who like programming challenges. They already want to see your idea for a challenge. You don't need a back story to make your challenge appeal to them. If you decide to include some context for the task, try to keep it short.

Personally, I'm more likely to be put off by a needlessly long challenge wording. If it's long because it's complex, I'll read it. If it's long because of telling a story to make a simple challenge more interesting, it actually becomes less interesting to me. Simple challenges are good. Let's keep them simple.

Answer (score 18):

## Adding special cases for the sake of completeness

This is a generalization of ["complicated" number types](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/61384), and is similar in scope to [adding unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/61384).

What I mean by this is that many challenges will try to make the problem well-defined for all possible inputs, when the challenge would have been much better if the set of inputs had been constrained more.

The challenge that prompted me to write this was [multiply a string and a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132002/61384). The basic idea is to repeat each character in a string a given amount of times. However, it also specifies what to do when the input number is negative, and the behavior is not a simple extension of the behavior for nonnegative inputs.

In my opinion, this special condition makes the challenge worse. I come to PPCG to solve interesting programming problems, and conditionally reversing a string based on whether a number is negative is not an interesting programming problem. It is unnecessary boilerplate that stops me from wanting to solve the challenge.

Furthermore, there are languages in which solving the problem is hard enough as it is. In the challenge linked above, one user decided to try and solve the problem in Retina. Retina was not designed for numeric handling, and the solution only worked for positive inputs. Thus, the edge condition stopped the answer from being competitive.

There are also languages such as Underload where input scope *would* be complete. In Underload, the most natural representation of numbers is whole numbers, and requiring that negative numbers be handled makes the challenge feel much more clunky.

In general, **always choose the smallest set of inputs for which the problem is well-defined and interesting, and only require submissions to handle those**. Anything else is edge cases, and handling edge cases is not fun.

Comment: I'm with you except for your choice of example. Answers can handle both the forward and reversed cases together ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132014/20260), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132007/20260)  [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132010/20260)) in clever ways for brevity,, and a challenge just to "copy each character n times" would have been nearly trivial.

Comment: @xnor I think it all comes down to target language. In this case the edge-case behavior does allow for some interesting solutions in certain languages. In the context of the languages I frequently golf in, however, it's nothing but boilerplate.

Comment: @xnor The problem, then, is that either the existing challenge or the simplified alternative would be closed as a dupe of the other, which means that there isn't a good way to balance having less but more clever solutions and having many solutions in more restricted languages. The only way I see for the second option to be preferred is if PPCG changed its voting habits and stopped upvoting more trivial challenges, something which has been brought up before but is beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: @xnor TL;DR You're right.

Answer (score 18):

## Exceptional edge cases

Don't require special behavior when the input is the empty list, the number 0, a negative length, etc. This makes for nasty surprises for solvers who worked on a solution only to find it's invalid on a technicality.

When possible, the edge case should follow the same rules as any other input without special instructions. However, even when the right answer is mathematically clear, it's often better to just specify the input will be non-empty, positive, etc, and avoid the issue altogether. If you do insist on including the edge case, do include a test case for it.

One place this comes up is the [string representation of 0](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8395/20260), which is conventionally `'0'` but mathematically is the empty string. Once in a while I find a nice recursive function that beats the boring built-in string conversion, but it fails the 0 test case, and it costs too many ugly bytes to patch. Specifying nonzero input would avoid this.

Answer (score 16):

### Assuming you've addressed sandbox feedback

When your challenge is in the sandbox and someone suggests a change or clarification, make sure your edit actually addresses their point. Too often the same complaints are brought up on the live challenge, and the poster is confused thinking they already dealt with them.

First, consider if the comment still holds true for your edited version. Maybe the rule is clearer than before, but still unclear. Maybe you've addressed some points but not others.

After editing, leave the challenge in the sandbox for more feedback. Maybe the change introduced new problems. Maybe the commenter will clarify their suggestions or offer further revisions. You can ping them in the comments to ask them to take another look.

Answer (score 16):

## Using the sandbox to "defend" your challenge

The sandbox is meant to be an aid to improve the challenge. But once posted to the main site, the quality of the challenge is entirely the poster's responsibility. Regardless of the sandbox, the challenge on the main site should be solid and well specified.

If you post to the main site and the challenge is found to have some flaw, having posted it in the sandbox first does not entitle you to anything. The fact is that the challenge has a flaw, and it should be corrected if possible, or else expect downvotes or close-votes. It's pointless to try to "defend" the challenge on the grounds that it spent several days in the sandbox and no one complained.

---

So why does it sometimes happen that people find the flaw on the main site and not in the sandbox? I see two main reasons:

- Fewer people see the challenge in the sandbox than on the main site;
- People who do see the challenge in the sandbox typically *read* it trying to find potential problems, but on the main site people try to *solve* it, which brings out problems more easily.

Possible solutions include:

- Try to call more attention to the challenge while in the sandbox, for example in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) chatroom.
- Ask someone to try to solve the challenge before posting.

---

Related: [*Assuming you've addressed sandbox feedback*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13040/36398)

Answer (score 14):

## Requiring multiple types as return value

This is very similar to [*Explicitly disallowing or disadvantaging arbitrary (classes of) languages*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/48198) though it's more subtle (and not necessarily explicit):

A lot of languages [don't allow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking) returning multiple types therefore it's not a good idea to require different types as a return value because it rules out those languages for no reason (of course there might be challenges exempt from this).

**Note:** While not requiring a different type, the same should hold for exit codes and errors - in some languages it is not possible to generate errors or certain exit codes.

#### Examples

- Given some input *X* if it satisfies property *Y* return a list of integers, else return a *falsy* value
- Given some input *X*, if it satisfies property *Y* return the integers *f(X)*, else return a string saying `zzz`
- Given the input *X* if it achieves *Y* return some *Z* else exit with a non-zero error cod
- Given *X* if it *Y*s then return some *Z* else error

Comment: One suggestion to fix this is to allow option types instead.  Most languages have some sort of option type.

Comment: @PostLeftGhostHunter: Yes that could solve it for a lot of "*non-recreative languages*" but that should be explicitly mentioned (I wouldn't call an `Either Bool [Int]` or `Optional<Integer>` *truthy* or *falsy*) and could still create problems for some esolangs.

Comment: I've long been uncomfortable with the arbitrariness of requiring "truthy or falsy". I prefer a requirement for two distinct consistent outputs. I can't see that a more specific requirement adds anything to most challenges.

Comment: @trichoplax: That would for example elegantly solve problems like example 1, but two distinct values *is* more specific than truthy/falsy.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes there *isn't* an example of a falsey value for that return type. Perhaps in these cases it might be better to let users assume that the input will always be valid

Comment: @JoKing They can use (equivalent of) C++ optional type (or a pair<bool,T>) (although it depends on whether doing both input verification and computing the output at once is interesting)

Answer (score 14):

## Parsing expressions

In challenges dealing with algebraic expressions, don't make the golfer parse input strings like `x^3-2x+1` or `e^2^x`, or to output in this form. This is [cumbersome I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260) that takes a lot of bytes and effort in languages that aren't like Mathematica, distracting from the actual mathematical task. For instance, a challenge about differentiating polynomials should allow them to be represented as lists of coefficients.

If you do insist on allowing a broad class of nested expressions like `2^(x+3)`, consider allowing them in a pre-parsed tree like `["Exp", 2, ["Plus", Var("x"), 3]]`. But, make sure you give a precise, comprehensive description of exactly what operations and values can be included. Try to include as few operations as is necessary for the challenge to work.

Beware that not all expressions are algebraically "nice", and make sure your test cases cover the gamut of possible expressions. In particular, consider how to deal with things like `x/0` or `0^0` or `(-2)^(1/2)` or `(x*x)**0.5/x`.

Make sure your problem is actually solvable. Note that there provably [doesn't exist any algorithm to decide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem) whether an expression in a real variable `x` is always zero for every `x`, if certain operations and constants are allowed. So, your challenge might be outright impossible.

Answer (score 14):

## Multipart challenges with unrelated sub-tasks

In general, a challenge on Code Golf should focus on a single core task. Challenges with multiple sub-tasks are discouraged, especially when the sub-tasks have zero or very little interaction or common aspects.

If the answer to at least one of the following questions is "yes", your challenge has a high chance to be poorly received on Code Golf.

1. If the sub-tasks are posted as individual challenges, are they interesting on their own, or are some of them already on Code Golf?

   - If multiple individual sub-tasks are already on Code Golf, your challenge has a high risk of getting closed as duplicate. [An extreme example.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141293/78410)
2. If you collect golfed answers to individual sub-tasks and simply merge into one, is it likely to be competitive?

One type of newbies' challenges is "replicate this small but multi-function utility", which suffers from being multipart by definition. (Note that they often also suffer from other kinds of quality problems, such as [rigid I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/78410), [input validation/error handling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/78410), and sometimes lack of clarity due to [random numbers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/78410) or [arithmetic expressions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19357/78410).)

More in-depth discussion can be found [in this post by Martin Ender](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/78410).

Answer (score 11):

## Problems without solutions

When writing a challenge, make sure it is actually solvable within the framework of recreational programming. While a task like "Identify objects in a picture" is certainly a difficult programming challenge, it's not something people can solve in an afternoon: The entirety of the computer science field has been working on cracking that nut for decades and still hasn't found a satisfactory solution.

Therefore, when posting a challenge, you should have at least a clear idea of an algorithm that can perform the task you want, and that you could implement in a reasonable amount of time. Ideally, you'd even have written and tested it. (Such an implementation wouldn't need to be golfed, or pretty, or even fast: The points is that you can prove by example that it's possible to solve the problem.)

Comment: One notable class of problems that falls in this category is [undecidable problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems), which means that they are mathematically *proven* to be impossible to solve with code. They are blatantly off-topic because they are literally not answerable on this site.

Comment: Upgoat or Downgoat...

Answer (score 11):

## Think twice if you're writing a challenge around an algorithm you found on the Internet

Simply put, it will never work as you expect, (though it could work as "a challenge") unless you pick *your algorithm and the problem* very carefully.

- If you make it a plain [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) without any restrictions, answers are free to choose brute force (which works universally since we don't require "it should run in practice" kind of thing, and is guaranteed to be golfier in all languages).
- If you make it a [restricted-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-time), a heuristic search might suffice, and you're possibly penalizing slow languages from faster ones. [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) might work, but it wouldn't if your algorithm's time complexity (or the problem's) is not very well-defined in terms of the input (could be only empirically fast, or depend on additional parameters like [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm)).
- If you make it a [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) or [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm), you need to choose your problem where the intended algorithm would work well, *and* study additional algorithms that might also work (comparable complexity or empirical performance). In addition, [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) might not work for the same reasons as [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity).

Answer (score 11):

## Real-valued output without further specification, or with a bad one

For integer outputs, you can check correctness with exact equality. For exact fractions, many challenges require to output a (numerator, denominator) pair which has worked out pretty well in practice.

But for **real number** outputs, the situation is totally different. All we have is floating-point numbers, which is a mere approximation of real numbers. Since it is an approximation, the challenge needs a requirement on accuracy as a validity criterion. And **writing a good requirement on accuracy is HARD**. Here are some guidelines to consider when writing such a challenge.

- **Use relative error**. "Should output within a [relative error](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html) of \$e\$" means that, if the true value is \$x\$ and the output is \$y\$, \$\frac{|x-y|}{x} \le e\$. The value of \$e\$ is commonly set to \$10^{-6}\$, but can be adjusted as necessary. (More on this below.)

  Or even better, use "absolute or relative error" (use absolute error when the expected result is less than 1 in magnitude, and relative error otherwise) when the result can be small as well. Some (theoretically correct) algorithms may fail to handle sufficiently small numbers and just give 0, which always has a relative error of 1 by definition.

  - ["Should output within 1 of the correct answer"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/256106/78410) is saying about [absolute error](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteError.html). It is bad if the result can be arbitrarily large, as it requires more and more correct digits as the expected result increases, and eventually it will go outside the limits of usual floating-point numbers (usually 64-bit for most languages).
- Consider various ways to compute the given function. One could use numerical integration (e.g. Riemann sums), iterative convergence (e.g. Newton's method), or maybe a simple approximation formula exists. These should be taken into account in various aspects, such as the following.

  - Decide which methods to disallow. Maybe an approximation formula looks too cheap? Then you might need to tighten the error margin \$e\$ (mentioned above) and provide test cases where the formula doesn't produce close enough values.
  - Does the task contain some extreme cases (the output is 0, +/- infinity, undefined or otherwise discontinuous)? The best option in that case is "the inputs close to such extreme points won't be given".
- Ensuring the error limit for *all possible inputs* is extremely hard, and most of us simply don't know how to prove it. So it is better to give multiple test cases and specify that an answer "should output within error **for the given test cases**".

[Circumference of an ellipse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211763/78410) (Disclaimer: one of my challenges) is a reference of a well-specified real-valued task.

Comment: I thought \$e\$ was 2.718 …

Answer (score 9):

## Exclamation marks in titles!

Quite a lot of questions have exclamation marks at the end of their titles! To me this just seems like a vain attempt to attract more attention with the hope of getting more upvotes!  I don't think I've ever seen a challenge with an exclamation mark in the title where the exclamation mark enhances the challenge in any way!

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial) is the only challenge I could see it being appropriate for.

Comment: The only exception I could think of are titles which happen to be quotes that include the exclamation mark in the original source.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyRLFWF2v_U

Comment: -1 And so does any non-straightforward title.

Comment: It means the bad challenge title is for example : "Monday Mini-Golf #6: Meeesesessess upp teeexexextext" But the good challenge title is : "Do the webtollkit messing tranform in shortest code possible."

Comment: @Christian actually, no. I'm only attempting to address exclamation marks here as IMO they are in their own category of pointless. I am not trying to address other styles of title - interesting, creative, boring or otherwise

Comment: If the title is an imperative sentence ([Make a slow error quine maker!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51007/make-a-slow-error-quine-maker)) or an exclamation ([My god, it's full of spaces!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/my-god-its-full-of-spaces)), I fail to see the problem.

Comment: @Dennis To me, *imperative sentence with exclamation mark* implies *forceful command*.  Perhaps we're different at PPCG, but in my experience *forceful commands* don't go over that well in questions on other .SE sites.  Fair point about your second example though.

Comment: The only time I've done this are to get around the 15 char limit for titles and I don't see how it really causes any harm to the actual challenge.

Answer (score 9):

## Consider if your challenge really needs random output

Challenges that require [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) output require extra clarifications that challenges with deterministic output do not, and additionally exclude languages with no source of non-determinism.

Often times randomness only acts as a [cumbersome output format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/56656), adding the randomness boilerplate from whatever language (or preventing submissions in that language).

At the same time there are few benefits that it provides to a challenge.

If there are a finite number of valid outputs for every input (which seems to be the majority of [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) challenges) you can change a challenge from

> Generate a random X

to

> Output all Xs

Of course there are other ways to remove unnecessary randomness, for example if challenges of the form:

> Generated a random X that satisfies property Y

often (but not always) break down into two challenges

> Generate a random X

and

> Given an X determine if it satisfies property Y

And you will often find a more worthwhile challenge in one of these two (or both).

---

Of course there are challenges that are best with random outputs. The clearest case of this are challenges that ask to generate output with a specific distribution, where meeting the specific distribution is the challenge.

Some examples of such challenges

- [Shortest code to produce non-deterministic output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638)

Answer (score 9):

## Requiring time limits

This may differ depending on your opinion, as quite a lot of challenges have time restrictions, but, for me, this is a form of [requiring a minimum score](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928/66833).

If a challenge is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), unless the *specific* goal of the challenge is to do the task quickly, adding a time limit simply prevents people from posting good answers and adds nothing positive to the challenge. Older challenges are more guilty of this, but occasionally a new challenge will be posted requiring answers to finish within X minutes.

A lot of challenges that contain a time limit often do so in an attempt to make the challenge more interesting. Banning specific builtins, classes of languages or other arbitrary things has been repeatedly shown to not make a challenge more interesting (see the other answers in this thread), so requiring answers to meet a specific time limit is unlikely to as well.

Furthermore, timing is non-perfect. What takes 5 seconds on one computer may take 50 on another. That's why we require specifications to be provided for [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), otherwise it's no longer objective. [TryItOnline](https://tio.run) has a time limit of one minute, so could possibly be used for such a time restriction. However Dennis - the host of TIO - has said repeatedly that TIO isn't reliable enough for [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), and so probably isn't accurate enough for time limits.

The worst culprits in my experience are [chameleon challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/66833), which detail an inefficient algorithm/method to complete the task, then all but outlaw that method by requiring answers to meet a time limit (see a lot of the older [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) challenges for example)

Obviously, this is a matter of opinion; some people prefer to see solutions finish, others don't mind. However, when considering adding in a time limit, ask yourself if it actually improves the challenge or just prevents otherwise valid answers from being posted.

---

As an aside, this isn’t to say that you should never include a time limit. Challenges where the sole aim is to “Do this thing quickly and golfy” are the main areas where a time limit works. Challenges where the aim is “Do this thing golfy. Oh and make sure you choose an algorithm that isn’t too slow” are a poor idea. Instead, look into either [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), or consider using an asymptotic complexity limit, [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity), which is much more objective.

Comment: Instead of time limits, is there a better way to say “Don’t just brute force the answer”? Or do you think people shouldn’t even try to stop brute force solutions?

Comment: @water_ghosts “no brute forcing” is, IMO, an unobservable requirement (another thing to avoid). I don’t think people shouldn’t try to stop brute forcing (and similar), I just think that a lot of good challenges are ruined by adding an unnecessary time limit. If a challenge works well with a time limit, good for it, but that doesn’t mean most don’t

Comment: Can't we just assume most answers will be in good faith? Those that do (purposely) use brute force just won't be upvoted as much.

Comment: @water_ghosts Asymptotic time complexity is a observable requirement even if it is not computable.  So if you need to ban brute force solutions you can simply require that all solutions be of a certain big O complexity class.  However I would seriously consider *why* you want to ban brute force answers and make sure that it would make the challenge more interesting.

Comment: I think time limits have a good use in combinatorics golf challenges where they prevent boring brute-force try-everything solutions and so encourage golfing that is actually specific to the problem. For these challenges, limiting computational complexity is usually overkill (and can be tricky to specify rigorously), and the difference between code that takes `2^1000` operations and `1000` operations usually makes specifics of timing not matter.

Comment: There should be a way to ask for golfed answers that are not brute force. An obvious way is to set a time limit. If we don't like that we need to think of another way.

Answer (score 4):

### Pure programming puzzles

Despite our name, [programming puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) aren't generally welcome here. I'm talking about challenges where you're given a task with some impossible-seeming restrictions and must use some clever trick or language feature to solve it.

Programming puzzles are closed most of ther time for not having an [objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): something that lets you compare submissions to decide a winner. A criterion for a valid solution is not enough -- others need to be able to do better and beat the solution. You could say the first valid solution wins, but some people find it unsatisfying that someone else can win before they even see the challenge. It's better when more people can participate in and enjoy a challenge.

If it makes sense for your challenge, you can say the shortest solution wins (code golf) or have some other metric. This is best for puzzles that can be solved by more than one method, so the search for better methods can be interesting. Beware that once someone posts a solution to the puzzle, others can see it and copy the key idea with a better-scoring implementation.

Comment: As a sidenote, I don't think programming puzzles should necessarily be off-topic. It seems that whether [pure programming puzzles are on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5585/20260) is still up for debate, but the reality seems to be that such questions get closed, so it's kinder to well-intentioned newbies to warn against posting them.

Comment: For those not familiar with the history: [Is the name of the community correct?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/is-the-name-of-the-community-correct) showed strong community support that "Puzzles" in the site name should be changed, so we would be "Programming Contests & Code Golf", which would allow all types of competitive contests, and avoid puzzles without a winning criterion.

Comment: The more recent discussion [Should we change our name](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/should-we-change-our-name) showed more support for keeping the current name, but there are lots of different issues mixed up in choosing a name, so I'm glad this answer now provides a place for voting on whether programming puzzles without a winning criterion should be avoided.

Comment: To reduce the problem of instant voting without reading the full content, would it be useful to change the title to **"Programming puzzles without a winning criterion"** or **"Programming puzzles without a scoring method"**?

Comment: @trichoplax Good idea, I changed it to "Pure programming puzzles".

Comment: From https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic : "Non-challenge questions that are related to solving programming puzzles or a particular type of challenge are also on topic."

Answer (score 4):

## Challenges whose validity can only be judged based on an external source

[Based on this discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25421/91213)

Avoid writing challenges like "scrape this website" or "use this API" or reproduce some website. Things on the internet change or go down all the time. If this happens all answers will be invalidated.

Instead, try to fix the relevant parts in your code. "Send a API request matching this JSON schema to this URL". Even if the URL no longer exists or has changed, you can still validate if submissions send something matching the schema.

For something like scrapping you can do the same. Include a text like "Assume the response will be formatted like the following" and then include a HTML sample.

Of course, if you are straying from a real site anyways you could consider simplifying these resources. If they don't have to match a real site you could remove parts that don't add much fun to the actual golfing.

Answer (score -7):

## [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) with easy fallback to general find-a-solution

Actually lot of these question do have one, the first few I see:

- [It almost works (Cops' Thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231321/) (`t=input();f(t);print()`)
- [The Math is Right, But the Answer is Wrong - Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217598/) (`f(input())?1e999-1e999:0`)
- [Guess my password (cops' thread)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213962/) (`f(input())`)
- [Peel away the layers - Cops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212068/) (code[`x+='0'`], code[`x+='1'`], checker)

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what makes these solutions an easy fallback and why that is bad for challenges.

Comment: @xnor I think `what makes these solutions an easy fallback` is trivial and so is `why that is bad for challenges.`(that's why `close as duplicate` exist)

Comment: So I've scrolled past this post quite a few times and still have no idea what a "general find-a-solution" is. Maybe I'd agree if it was clarified but now I'm just super confused.

Answer (score -13):

### Entirely nonsensical rationales for short code length.

This was fun (and was documented as a [local meme](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5856/20469)) when the rationales vaguely made sense, for example, "We want the program that does this to be as small as possible so it can fit into the margins" (from [The Margin is too Narrow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57363/the-margin-is-too-narrow)).

However, this has gotten out of hand. Recently more challenges have included rationales that make absolutely no sense, in or out of context. For example, "Because you can only stack about 5 goats before they start to fall, your code will need to be as short as possible" (from [Tokenize a Stack-Based language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69031/20469), since edited out).

In an effort to keep challenge specs concise and readable, I propose that we do the following when we see something clearly off-topic for the challenge in the spec:

- Edit the question
- Link here in the edit description (it will appear in the revision history)
- Send attack drones

Comment: "Send attack drones" is an entirely nonsensical solution to these entirely nonsensical rationales. :P

Comment: Just wondering, did Trichoplax post this question just so you could post this answer? Are you Trichoplax in disguise?

Comment: Chemistry-tagged challenge: Because there are only 6.022140857×10^23 atoms in a mole, your co... (yawn) :-D

Comment: @steveverrill Haha no, I think trichoplax would have posted this question anyway, though I think if I hadn't posted this answer, he would have. ;)

Comment: What counts as entirely nonsensical? I've used ["However, I've gotten lazy in my old age. So I'm outsourcing it to you, and disguising it as a code golf challenge."](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61008/14215), which I think could count as either nonsensical or perfectly reasonable, depending on whether you believe it or not.

Comment: @Geobits That's not a rationale for short code length though. But I think people should use judgment as to whether something is entirely irrelevant to the spec and should be removed.

Comment: The only problem with individual judgement in this case is that something only has to annoy one person to result in an edit, even if no one else finds it annoying. There's something to be said for @NathanMerrill's suggestion in the comment on this meta question.

Comment: I suggest downvoting. This would be too subjective if people begin to look for workarounds. Having a dumb rule may make it seemed interesting looking for workarounds to some askers.

Comment: i don't care enough to vote but i will say that i'd feel kind of weird about a rule dictating what kind of jokes you're allowed to tell on this site

Comment: I don't think this answer is a perfect fit for the question, because "*no longer funny*" implies that it was funny once...

Comment: @PeterTaylor this is a good point, and makes me realise I phrased the question poorly. I've edited to hopefully improve this.

Comment: What about the ones that make sense? Also most of them are at the bottom of the post, I'm not sure how that affects readability.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that just because you don't find the ridicuous jokes funny but I do, I'm not allowed to put them in my challenge rationale? *pah*

Comment: @cat It's not because they aren't funny, it's because they clutter the specs. Short code rationales add nothing to challenges.

Comment: They add humor (subjectively), in much the same way that things like struck-through "instructions" for the [puppy command](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74960/14215) do, for instance. I'd be hard pressed to say the puppy commands add *less* clutter, given that they're within the actual instructions and not as a fore/afterword.

Comment: @Geobits You have a fair point. I'll concede that the short code rationales aren't always so bad.