# What is/are the reasons for this being put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Can someone explain specifically why this is currently on hold? I'd really like to be able to turn this into a contest, but I'm not sure what's disagreeable about it.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73215/42091

Comment: [See this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8325/the-state-of-the-underhanded-tag) and [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/has-underhanded-been-getting-too-much-like-code-trolling)

Comment: So it should be re-opened if I remove the `underhanded` tag and remove the optional "appears to" clause?

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak on behalf of the folks who voted to close your challenge, but here's my take.

The post was put on hold as "too broad." The specific text doesn't make a whole lot of sense in the context of this site, but it still gives the gist:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Basically, the spec is too open-ended. There are too many ways to do it, especially because standard loopholes are allowed. *Standard* loopholes are standard for a reason.

Also note that the underhanded aspect is quite likely (at least partially) to blame for the downvotes. As Downgoat noted in a comment, [underhanded challenges have fallen out of favor](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8325/the-state-of-the-underhanded-tag). In my opinion, and I believe many others feel this way as well, challenges that say "do X but make it look like you aren't" (et cetera) aren't interesting.

I hope this has been able to provide at least a little context. But don't be discouraged! I recommend posting challenges to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where they can get meaningful feedback prior to being posted to the main site.