# Standard Loopholes Pertaining to [underhanded]

Tags: discussion, underhanded

On [our standard loopholes post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/61384), there
[are](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1657/61384)
[several](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1828/61384)
[different](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1283/613840)
[answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1739/61384)
that pertain to [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) questions.

Since the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) tag [has been retired](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8326/61384), there is no longer a need for these answers<sup>1</sup>. I posted comments on them suggesting that they be deleted, and one person responded that they would prefer a community consensus before they are deleted.

I'm getting a bit tired of seeing these every time I scroll through that page looking for something. Should they be deleted?

<sup>1</sup> The author of the one about [fake random numbers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1739/61384) suggested that that answer should be kept because it does not just apply to [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) contests, which I agree with. Should we still keep it?

Answer (score 11):

### Merge the answers and migrate them here

... or anywhere with the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) tag that can be found by people who are still interested in the early history of PPCG.

I think these answers are of historical values and should be kept, just not in a way that interferes with the normal browsing of pages that serve as FAQs.

Comment: "I think these answers are of historical values and should be kept, just not in a way that interferes with the normal browsing of pages that serve as a FAQ purpose." Assuming the user in question is high enough in rep, this preservation is done by deleting the answers, which preserves them in the system (and allows them to be shown to high-rep users), but pushes them to the bottom.

Comment: They aren't necessary high enough in rep.

Comment: They're [stored](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108083211/https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) in the Wayback Machine anyway. If someone is curious, they can view them anyway.

Comment: They can as long as they know that has appeared there. Not something that can be searched by the PPCG search engine though.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit It doesn't necessarily push them to the bottom, at least not if you sort by "active".

Comment: Is that possible? I know it's possible to merge two questions and migrate all of the answers from one to the other, but I've never heard that it's possible to migrate individual answers.

Comment: I mean doing it manually. Of course the revision history will be lost but I am afraid that's the best we can do.

Comment: It's definitely not possible to migrate answers with mod tools. It would be pretty simple to write a script for, though.

Answer (score 2):

Delete them, they serve no purpose any more.