# New challange variant "Scored Code Golf"

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I have a new idea for code-golf challenges, scored code golf would be used for multi part challenges that correspond and the score adds up. This would allow for linking different challenge types together.

I need help knowing if this is a good/bad idea and ideas for rules. The real problem is you want as few bytes as possible but you want as many *points* as possible.

I was thinking bonus points for winning different places and one point per answer you beat (you can only beat users other then you and can only beat each user once)

I need some help with this and any advice is needed. Mainly will this work? And if it does what should be the rules and scoring system?

---

This appears to be a code challenge and I have edited the tag wiki so we have one for code-challenge. I think it will work like that but perhaps this could be a scoring variant.

Comment: Please don't edit the tag wiki without confirming, especially if you're going to make a meta post anyway.

Comment: [Related, possible dupe.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/should-multi-part-challenges-be-allowed)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea for a few reasons:

1. Challenges should be self-contained. Having scores in one challenge be influenced by scores in another challenge would make the challenge not self-contained.
2. The top score on a challenge changes frequently. You'd either need to keep the points updated (which would be a logistical nightmare), or set a deadline on the challenges (which is also frowned upon).
3. Your proposed scoring system disincentivizes users posting multiple answers, which is also not a good idea.

Comment: Ah this is for a specific three part challange