# Are GoL challenge on topic

Tags: discussion

I have a challenge idea that is pure Conway's Game of Life, would this be on topic on PPCG?

I know we already have [some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life), but it seems to me that they're just cool language restricted golf, which are frequently frowned upon here.

[sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10799/56245)

Comment: In principle yes, because you'll probably want a GoL-specific scoring method. (Number of live cells, size of bounding box, density of live cells, number of generations it takes to achieve the goal.) I recommend sandboxing your idea so we can talk about specifics.

Comment: If you sandbox it, please put a link to the post in your question. Also, if it's something that *can* be done in other languages, perhaps you could allow any language and see if someone would offer a bounty for an answer in Conway's Game of Life.

Comment: I'll use this as an opportunity to talk about encapsulating parts of GoL. There's a Universal Turing Machine, and it's possible to create a system that mimics running the whole turing machine off one side of the screen without actually running all its Life code for every cycle. If you drilled down into the board, the environment could show you the gliders bouncing around inside the turing machine, but when you zoom or pan away the system just fakes it to preserve CPU. Answers could be submitted as the program the turing machine runs plus whatever other initial cells you need to turn on.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

Think of it as a language-restricted challenge, like you said.  [These are allowed by meta consensus.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/should-language-specific-code-golf-challenges-be-explicitly-disallowed)