# Should "Operations with lists" be broken up into individual challenges?

Tags: discussion, policy, specific-question, challenge-quality

As it stands, [Operations on lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6257/45941) is in a bit of a weird place. It could be considered a multi-part challenge with minimal interaction between the subchallenges, which [aren't allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8464/45941), but is pointed to as a (potential or actual) dupe target for the tasks it requires.

Would it be better to break up this challenge into its constituent parts and post each as a separate challenge?

Comment: This is actually a case of a valid multi-part challenge since code reuse between the individual parts is possible (answers are a single program/function which returns all of the values). I'm not saying it's a great question, but it's not off-topic by the consensus you linked.

Comment: @MartinEnder I consider allowing code reuse to be a "small interaction", to use the terms of the referenced meta policy. However, I'll modify my wording to be more neutral.

Comment: Whether that's a small interaction or not depends highly on how much code reuse is actually possible (which isn't a terrible amount in this case, admittedly).

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, we should break it up

It's a multi-part challenge, which aren't allowed (the only interaction between the subchallenges is the restriction to a single language and the ability to reuse code, which is my eyes is a "small interaction", to use the terminology of the meta policy), and allowing it to remain open makes it a [broken window](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11082/45941).

I propose the following steps to rectify the situation:

1. Close the challenge as off-topic, citing our policy on multi-part challenges.
2. Post each of the statistics in the challenge as their own challenge (excepting those that already exist, like [median](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/106149/45941)):

   - Sum
   - Product
   - Arithmetic mean
   - Median
   - Adjacent differences (a.k.a. first-order discrete differences)
   - Sorting ascending
   - Minimum
   - Maximum
   - Standard deviation
3. Optionally move duplicate challenges' targets to the appropriate subchallenge. This isn't terribly important, but it would be nice to have the dupe targets correct.

Comment: Regardless of whether the challenge itself is off-topic or not, I agree that these tasks would be better served with separate well-written challenges for each of them that can act as dupe targets and repositories of solutions to standard problems.

Comment: Are there any subtasks which don't already exist as standalones and are interesting enough to be worth posting?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Whether or not the challenges would be interesting isn't quite the point - we need definitive versions of those challenges for dupe targets. Right now, having them all lumped together in one challenge makes it less clear whether or not a challenge is a duplicate or not.