# Multiple answers in a single post

Tags: discussion, policy, answers, community-wiki, specific-answer

Is is acceptable to bunch together multiple answers in a CW post just because the challenge is trivial?

See e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151280/43319.

Comment: @user202729 Yes. I've put in my vote.

Comment: I feel like I should explain my decision of CWing that answer: At the time I posted it my answer literally was "maxBy length" (2 chars) (I had to change it later since OP changed the rules). I agree that trivial challenges have trivial answers and that's ok, but that felt like cheating. I do think that the other answers (except the Jelly one) are substantially different and would be better off in a separate answer. Maybe it was a mistake to create that CW answer, but probably that whole challenge is (that's another issue though).

Comment: @BruceForte I personally see no reason to ever CW trivial answers together. It just makes it harder to participate, gain rep, receive comments, and it breaks the leaderboard too.

Comment: @BruceForte The K answer is certainly not trivial, and K is not a golfing language.

Comment: 1. Leaderboard can be fixed. 2. It's the poster's opinion to include it into the CW answer. 3. If it's indeed trivial, it can't be improved, and no comment is necessary.

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate. This particular answer doesn't seem to fit xnor's criterion for combined answers.

Comment: @Dennis: Certainly the answers `►L↔` (Husk) and `LÐṀḢ` (Jelly) do fit xnor's criterion. No?

Comment: @BruceForte They do not. *All* answers on PPCG are composed of built-ins, but xnor talks about *just-a-built-in answers*. `L`, `ÐṀ`, and `Ḣ` are *three* built-ins, not one.

Comment: @Dennis: Well I'm sorry I created that answer and (as I said before) I can't control what others put into that answer. As for my initial submission (for which I created the CW), it was *just-a-built-in*.

Comment: @BruceForte Isn't `►` and `L` two different things?

Comment: @user202729: `►` is only a combinator and wouldn't be a valid program/function.

Comment: But it's a **built-in** combinator. ......

Comment: @BruceForte It's still two tokens and, therefore, *two* built-ins. The *a* in *just a built-in* means *one*.

Comment: @Dennis: I understand now, sorry for initiating that answer.

Comment: So is the definition of trivial "a solution with a single operator"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## No, this is not acceptable

xnor's proposal to [combine equivalent trivial answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11218/12012) talks about solutions that are *just a built-in*. None of the answers in the post you mention are just rather; they all consist of at least three tokens. Furthermore, although the differences may be subtle, they certainly aren't all *equivalent*.

Aside from the fact that a single answer is now hogging the challenge for an arbitrary number of languages ([the Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151277/12012) isn't less trivial than the answer in the CW post), the answers aren't explained as well as they could be, there's a *huge* potential for editing conflicts as the post grows larger, votes cannot discriminate between good and bad solutions, and we've pinned a vertically large post to the top, furthermore decreasing the attention less trivial answers will get.

Personally, I can't see any *upsides* to making a huge CW posts for anything but one-step answers (the fact that there are *two* Jelly answers lumped in there shows that answers aren't as trivial as they're supposed to be). I propose to delete this answer and repost the solutions as separate answers, as they should have been posted in the first place.

Comment: I think it's clear from the discussions about "trivial solutions" in the last month that we need clear guidelines about what constitutes a trivial solution...