# I don't think my question is a dupe

Tags: discussion, reopening

How is [Language Agnostic Code Golf!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142213/language-agnostic-code-golf) a dupe of [Which language is shortest?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61955/which-language-is-shortest)? Sure the general ideas are the same, but the methodologies are totally different. It's a dupe because both questions involve adding up scores based on language, huh? The technical differences between the challenges are so multitudinous, I'm not sure why someone who read both would say mine is a dupe. Here are some differences:

1. **Original question**: Find 50 latest challenges with 20 or more answers.
   **My question**: Find 40 questions that have answers in both inputted languages.
2. **Original question**: Add up all the scores on all the questions. Get the averages. Return the 20 most common languages.
   **My question**: Add up the best scores for each question. Return the ratio of the first language's total to the second languages'.

Sure they're similar, but the techniques/queries used are different. If the techniques are different aren't they different? If there are two questions that say "Calculate Pi" but require different techniques, is one a dupe of the other?

My other argument is that [stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api) is a unique tag with not many questions. I don't think there is all that much variety in how that tag operates.

Comment: If there is *one* question which says "*Calculate Pi*" and requires a given technique, under current standards the question falls foul of ["Avoid non-observable program requirements"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194) and should be edited not to.

Answer (score 9):

## What's different?

> you need to find 40 questions that have both languages as answers, not "the 50 most recent questions with 25 or more answers"

That's really not that different. One of them's just more tedious because you have to go through more questions, but it's not all that different; just take an answer, change `50` to `1000`, apply a filter, and take the first 40 elements. I trust any language can do that pretty easily.

> you need to find the best-scoring answer for each language, not every answer

but in the question:

> *(technically there's a lower byte count answer under "JS" but you're not required to detect it.)

Huh? Please be consistent; either way, you have to look through all of the answers anyway so it's not going to be that different.

> The methodologies are very different, and I don't see how it's a dupe except for the general idea, which doesn't matter.

Actually, it's a dupe because of the general idea. The specifics are different but if that were enough to make it its own challenge we'd have a thousand variants on Hello World / Hello, World / Hello, world / Hello World! / etc...

**I don't think it's different enough to be its own challenge.**

You have failed to point out that yours takes input to compare two languages while the other extracts language names from the answers; however, that can be easily changed from that challenge to your challenge.

Comment: Your answer it is too much long. Analysis without synthesis is not good

Answer (score -5):

## It would've been fun...

Look, I really appreciate the effort that's been put into stopping code-trolling and closing obvious dupes and non-objective questions. However, I really think some people fail to give things a chance, and ignore the fact that while it take seconds to vote to close, it takes a significant amount of time to write a question.

Ultimately, my question was not the same as the other one. The metric is the same - the average length of the various languages - however the technique was different. The first involved looking at the 50 most recent large questions and pooling the results, whereas mine involved *only* looking at questions where both languages had an answer. The results could've been wildly different.

As far as my "Calculate Pi" comment - if one question said calculate Pi wit the Monte Carlo method and the other said calculate Pi with the co-primes method, shouldn't they both been allowed?

Anyway, it would've been fun...

Comment: It takes a significant amount of time to write a spam post. It takes seconds to flag and delete (I think our record is below 10 seconds to flag-delete a spam post). That's not a valid point. The metric is the same, but the technique was different - you'll see many questions that ask essentially the same thing presented differently - it's still a duplicate, just not word-for-word identical; that doesn't matter. As far as your "calculate pi" comment: those would be different because they have to do the algorithm differently; between the two being discussed, they're very similar because answers

Comment: from that question can be modified trivially to serve the purpose of your challenge as I explained in my answer.