# What exactly should be the format for the test cases?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Working on my [latest challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13690#13690), I realized that I don't know what is the optimal way of providing/formatting the test cases. So the question is, what is the best way for a challenger to provide test cases for a challenge?

Consider that

- the formatting should be such that if people simply copy and paste the test-case-code-block, it needs minimal handling to be used and tested.
- it should be easy to work with as many languages as possible.
- the format should be easy for humans reading the actual post on PPCG.

How can the total ease be maximized? Should the test cases be

```
n=3 -> T=1
n=4 -> T=8
n=5 -> T=35
n=6 -> T=110
n=7 -> T=287
n=8 -> T=632
n=9 -> T=1302
```

with little arrows in between? Or should they be

```
n=3, T=1
n=4, T=8
n=5, T=35
n=6, T=110
n=7, T=287
n=8, T=632
n=9, T=1302
```

comma separated? Or should I remove all unnecessary characters and only provide a numeric array delimited by commas, tab, space, or something like this?

```
3,1
4,8
5,35
6,110
7,287
8,632
9,1302
```

Or something else entirely?

Comment: Dunno what's optimal (I usually do something like `3 -> 1`), but definitely drop the `n=` and the `T=` - just have something like `n -> T` or `Input -> Output` at the top of the test cases

Comment: Depends on the type of input and output. Can I suggest narrowing the scope to ask only about questions which take input as an integer or a 1D list of integers and give output as an integer or 1D list of integers?

Comment: [See this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/59487), I think it pretty much covers everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It pretty much depends on the challenge

#### Math-related challenges

For math-related challenges, with small amounts of text for both input and output (i.e. numbers), I usually delimit them with an **ASCII** arrow (`->`), and put a header at the top showing what values I am working with (like `Input -> Output`):

```
n -> T

3 -> 1
4 -> 8
5 -> 35
6 -> 110
7 -> 287
```

However, if the challenge involves negative numbers as well, I would substitute `->` with `=>`, to avoid confusion.

#### String-related challenges with input (and output) of variable size

When I deal with strings (or numbers with variable number of digits), I use the same format but align the arrows and  use wide spacing*. For example:

```
Input -> Output 

abc          -> 3
abcde        -> 5
ppcg         -> 4
codegolf.SE  -> 11
```

<sub>*In my opinion this is the best compromise between ease of use and human readability.</sub>

#### ASCII-Art challenges

When the output contains multiple lines, you can have the input and output separated by newlines. Some examples:

```
Input
Output


3
+---+
|   |
+---+

4
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+

.....
```

---

As a reference, [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8101#8101) is very on-topic in this case.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize that this had already been specifically addressed in that reference.