# How do esolangs participate in a challenge about black-box inputs?

Tags: discussion

Please refer to [this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20814/89459) on Sandbox.

The input is a black-box function, but as someone not knowing much of esolangs and golfing languages, I cannot even imagine how they accept black-box functions as input.

I can generalize this situation like the following: Mathematically, the input domain is not a [discrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space). Examples, using topology terms:

- The input is a function. In other words, the domain is a function space consisting of continuous functions, endowed with the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).
- The input is an iterator with no guarantee of terminating. In this case, the domain is a [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)) of a discrete space with infinitely many points, resulting in a non-discrete space.
- At worst, the input has no guarantee of halting when evaluated, and if it halts, the evaluation result is to be discarded. In this case, the domain is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), which is not [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space).

It already seems most esolangs cannot handle such inputs. For example, Brainfuck only handles user-inputted chars, and the space of strings is discrete.

Do black-box functions inevitably prohibit a class of languages from participating, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It's not a issue if some languages can not participate in every challenge

There is a [guideline not to exclude certain languages arbitrairly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/91213) but if some language simply is unable to solve a challenge that is no reason not to pose the challenge.

Also, many esolangs do have a way to input a black box function, eg. as a string to be `eval`ed

Comment: Writing a self-interpreter in brainfuck is a fun activity I encourage everyone to try at least once in their lifetime

Comment: You can also write a function if your esolang supports it that takes a function as input, not necessarily a full program.